# Extract content of a string by using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have text like <GetSupportUrls>b__5

The resultant output should be te content between the angle brackets(<) and (>) i.e. GetSupportURLs here..

I am trying with the below Regular Exp but no luck

```
var result= Regex.Match("<GetSupportUrls>b__5", @"\<([^>]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Please help

Comment: Programming isnt based on luck, what went wrong?

Comment: You've forgotten to match closing bracket."<GetSupportUrls>b__5", @"\<([^>]*)\>\\)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is looking for a closing *parenthesis*, not an angle bracket. Try

```
var result= Regex.Match("<GetSupportUrls>b__5", @"<([^>]*)>").Groups[1].Value;
```

(You don't need to escape the `<>` characters, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex:

```
(?<=<).*?(?=>)
```

This will make the match the value between the `<` and `>`  characters. 
It uses positive lookahead and lookbehind to check for the `<>` characters without actually matching them.

Code example:

```
string resultString = null;
try
{
    resultString = Regex.Match(part, "(?<=<).*?(?=>)").Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

And the documentation:

```
  // Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=<)»
//    Match the character “<” literally «<»
// Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=>)»
//    Match the character “>” literally «>»
```

Comment: This fails if more than one tag is present in the text.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your text is XML, so I would suggest using System.Xml to process the data.

Try something like:

```
 void string GetSupportUrls()
 {
     var doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load (...);  // your text
     return doc
       .SelectSingleNode("GetSupportUrls")
       .InnerText;
 }
```

Comment: It's probably not XML but a method generated by the compiler for a LINQ expression (or something similar) and even if it was XML your code would get the text inside the node and not the node name that he wants.

Comment: If OP wants the node then use 'OuterText' instead of 'InnerText".  Also, I think it is bad practice to use Regex on Xml.  If the data is XML then use System.Xml; if its plain text then Regex should be used. 

A Regex cannot easily cope with a <![CDATA[ ... ]]> in the inner text; which can legally be in any element.

Comment: Well as I said it's probably not XML :).